# Render - Problem connecting to the remote database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, render, render.com

I launched a simple site in nodejs with registration on RENDER.com
I can't connect to remote postgresql database.
Between render.com and elephantsql.com
However, when I run the site from the local level, the connection is established.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLZD0.png)
I am asking for help, advice, someone experienced.

my file .env

```
DB_USER=xulfmyss
DB_PASSWORD=kp2-neM1e4Ba6cX
DB_HOST=tuffi.db.elephantsql.com
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=xulfmyss
```

my file configDB,js

```
    require("dotenv").config();
const {Pool} = require("pg");
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const connetion = `postgresql://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_DATABASE}`; 
const  pool = new Pool(
    {
        connectionString: isProd ? process.env.DB_DATABASE_URL : connetion 
    }
)
module.exports = {pool}
```

Comment: It appears you are connecting to 127.0.0.1 which is your localhost IP address. Maybe you need to update the DB connection details, or create two separate configurations, one for localhost, one for remote deployments.

Comment: Thank you for answering
I use this configuration in the .env file
DB_USER=xulfmyss
DB_PASSWORD=kp2-neM1e4Ba6cX
DB_HOST=tuffi.db.elephantsql.com
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=xulfmyss

Comment: The `DB_DATABASE_URL` environment variable is not set up correctly

Answer (score 1):

If your are here because you were trying to connect to Render's Postgres using the local host and it failed. You should remember that your database and app must be in the same region for that to work.

For instance, if your app was hosted in `Frankfurt`, your database must alse be hosted in `Frankfurt`.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path. On your remote PostgreSQL db (Render) you should see "External Database URL" below Connection. Use this and paste on .env file.

Make sure to add  `?ssl=true` at the end of the string to prevent SSL errors that node will throw.

```
.env

DB_CONNECTION_STRING = postgres://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOSTNAME/DATABASE
```